# A bot that writes a message itself does not answer

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a question about the bot on the messenger.
Can I make a bot that writes to a person every day, counting down for example days?
I know it's easy to create a bot that responds, but can you do it so that you can write to someone without any interaction from that person?

Comment: Congratulations on your first Stack Overflow question!  Have you searched (either internet generally, or other questions on here) to see if there's any information out there? People may find it easier to help you if they have an idea where you've already looked or what you've already tried. Or if you've hit a dead-end, let us know what you've tried searching so we know what **not** to try.

Comment: No, not for just any arbitrary content. For news publishers there is Subscription Messaging, but you got to actually _be_ a news publisher. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview#new_subscription_messaging